# Rotating Bits, using sizeof operator

Tags: sizeof

I'm trying to write a bit rotator function and I'm trying to get more clarification the sizeof operator.  Since I don't know what type of numerical object I need to rotate, I assume I need to use the sizeof operator for

```
unsigned rotator(unsigned object, int count)
```

this function prototype where object is the object to be rotated and count is the number of bits to be moved.  I am imagining that if I had an 8 bit number, I first would determine the actual number of bits to be rotated (since the person can make count = 20 for example, so I would do something like:

```
int actualBitRotation;
if (count > sizeof(object)) {
    actualBitRotation = count % sizeof(object);
```

But I don't think I understand sizeof correctly still.  I did try reading online resources about it and have received some help from this board on it with another problem, but I don't think I get it.  I know sizeof returns the number of bytes in the object, so would I include  and instead do something more like

```
int actualBitRotation;
if (count > (sizeof(object) * CHAR_BIT) {
    actualBitRotation = count % (sizeof(object) * CHAR_BIT);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sizeof() does return the number of bytes so you need to multiply by CHAR_BIT to get the number of bits.

```
template<typename T> T bitrot(T& t,size_t bits) {
   bits %= (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT);
   return ((t >> (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT)-bits) | (t << bits));
}
```

To clarify, you should always avoid shifting operations beyond the number of bits in the variable; the results are processor- and compiler- dependent.

Comment: I think Crystal was asking about what happens if you rotate more then the number of bits in the int.

So at the beginning of your bitrot() function put:
  bits = bits % (sizeof(T)*CHAR_BITS);

Comment: In fact, shifts must be *less than*  the width of the type, so when bits=0, you've actually got a problem in the above. Will not usually manifest: n>>32 is equiv to n>>0 on pentiums, thus the '|' hides it. It seems to me that in the original K&R (I lost my copy) shifts were allowed <= width, but the newer one says must be < the width. Anybody have an old K&R? I'm curious, because intel's first variable shift operation (on 80186) looked at 5 lsbs of CL, and thus shifts of 16-bit values worked from 0 to 16 bits. With the 386 they left it at 5 bits for 32-bit regs. Did intel thus break C?

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
union hack {
    int asSigned;
    unsigned asUnsigned;
};
hack top, bottom;
int realBitCount = count % (sizeof(T)*8);
top.asSigned = (realBitCount == 0) ? 0 : -(1 << (realBitCount-1));
bottom.asUnsigned = 0xFFFFFFFF ^ top.asUnsigned;

top.asUnsigned &= object;
bottom.asUnsigned &= object;
return static_cast<T>( (bottom.asUnsigned << realBitCount) | (top.asUnsigned >> (sizeof(T)-realBitCount)) );
```